# How can I prove following lemma in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am trying to write a Coq poof for the following lemma:

```
Require Export Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.
Require Import FMapAVL.
Module M := FMapAVL.Make(Nat_as_OT).

Fixpoint cc (n: nat) (c: M.t nat):bool :=
match M.find n c with
| None => false
| _ => true
end.

Lemma l: forall (n: nat) (k:nat) (m: M.t nat), cc n m = true  -> cc n (M.add k k m) = true.
```

I'm unable to simplify `(M.add k k m)` part.

Comment: What is `M`?  Can you add necessary imports?  Also, what have you tried doing and at what point are you unable to simplify `(M.add k k m)`.  It would be helpful if you could list all tactics used up to the point that you get stuck.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to look into the contents of stuff in a module, you should only use the lemmas defined in the module to reason about the abstract data type M.  In this case it is sufficient to use the lemmas `M.add_1`, `M.add_2`, `M.find_1`, `M.find_2`.

Comment: See i.e. [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8173a55317b5cfc4450a1a1e172f01b) for one way to prove the lemma.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no recursive call in `cc`, so you should make this definition a plain definition (using keyword `Definition` instead of `Fixpoint`).

Second, if you want to reason about the behavior of `M.find` and `M.add`, you should
look at the theorems stating things about these functions:  theorems
`M.find_2`, `M.add_2`, `M.E.eq_dec`, and `M.add_1` will be useful (I found these lemmas by using the `Search` command).  So start by unfolding `cc`, then reason by cases on the value of (`M.find n m`), then use these
theorems to progress logically about the functions occurring in your statements.  Please note that function `M.MapsTo` plays a key role in this problem.

I would rather not give you the solution because it looks like an elementary exercise in reasoning about tables.

Comment: Search command is not showing me any output for `Search M.add` or `Search M.find`. This is how I think it should be used based on online documentation. Am I doing it wrong? I have used all the necessary imports, it compiles but shows nothing.

Comment: I was using Proof General and type <ctrl-C><ctrl-F>M.find<return> and it gave me M.find_1 M.find_2 and a third theorem with their statements.  I also tried typing the command "Search M.find." and it returned the right theorems. The version of Coq I am using is 8.6.  I will tried with coqide when I have time and report on the results here.

Comment: Using coqide (8.6.1) I can open the query pane (using an option from the View menu) and type M.find.  I also get three theorems.