# Why inversion tactic doesn't work in the following Coq proof?

Tags: coq

```
Require Import FMapAVL.
Require Import OrderedTypeEx.

Module M := FMapAVL.Make(Nat_as_OT).
Fixpoint cc (n: nat) (c: M.t nat):bool :=
  match M.find n c with
  | None => false
  | Some e => true
  end.

Lemma l: forall (n: nat) (k:nat) (m: M.t nat), cc n m = true  -> cc n (M.add k k m) = true.
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H.
```

Environment before calling `inversion H`:

```
1 subgoals
n : nat
k : nat
m : M.t nat
H : cc n m = true
______________________________________(1/1)
cc n (M.add k k m) = true
```

Based on my understanding of inversion tactic, using tactic `inversion H`, should be able to predict `M.find n m = Some e`. But it just duplicates H.

Can someone please help me with how Coq is interpreting things here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inversion works when the hypothesis' main predicate is an inductive predicate.  Here the main predicate of hypothesis `H` is an equality, and it happens that deep inside equality is represented by an inductive predicate.  So `inversion` think it can work.

Intuitively, `inversion` tries to help you reason on what constructor could have been used, and this reasoning is made by adding equality statements that correspond to the constraints that have to be satisfied when this constructor is used to prove the hypothesis.

In your case, equality is represented by an inductive definition with only one constructor.  So `inversion` looks at what the constraints for using this constructor are: the two members of the equality should be the same.  So `inversion` adds a new equality stating that the two sides of the equality should be the same.  This is why you see this duplication of the hypothesis.

It just happens that `inversion` is not the right tactic to use here.

In a previous answer to one of [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46368346/1809211), I wrote that you should not use `Fixpoint` to define the function `cc`, because this function is not recursive.  Please follow my advise and write

```
Definition cc (n: nat) (c: M.t nat):bool :=
match M.find n c with
| None => false
| Some e => true
end.
```

This will make the rest of the proofs easier (we can also solve your problem with `cc` defined using `Fixpoint` but it adds unnecessary complications).  My answer to your question now supposes that you did follow this
piece of advice.  Here is how to progress about your proof.

```
Proof.
intros n k m H; unfold cc in H.
```

At this point your hypothesis `H` contains an equality between a pattern matching statement and `true`.  What you want is to study the two possible computations of this match statement, by performing the same case analysis in your proof.  Here is how to do it.

```
case_eq (M.find n m); [intros v Hfind | intros Hfind].
```

After this, you will have two goals.  One has `H : match ... with ... end = true` and `Hfind : M.find n m = Some v`, the other has `H : match M.find n m with ... end = true` and `Hfind : M.find n m = None`.  Using `Hfind` to rewrite in `H` you will change the hypothesis into `H : false = true`, that will be solvable using `discriminate`.  Keep this in mind for later.

For the first goal, you should be able to progress again by `unfold cc`.

Now what is the value of `M.find n (M.add k k m)`?  If `n` is `k` this value is `Some k`.  If `n` is different from `k` the value of `M.find n (M.add k k m)` is the same as the value of `M.find n m`.  We already gave a name to this value, this name is `v` and the hypothesis `Hfind` says so.

To produce the case analysis on whether `n` is equal to `k` I suggest you write `destruct (M.E.eq_dec k n) as [kn | knn]`.

So you will have a first goal with hypothesis `kn : k = n`.  In that case I suggest you prove an intermediate fact by typing the following command.

```
assert (step : M.find n (M.add k k m) = Some k).
```

This you should be able to prove using `M.find_1`, `M.add_1`.

Once you are finished with this proof, rewrite with `step` and then conclude.

Then you will have a second goal with hypothesis `knn : k <> n`, for this one you have to prove a different intermediate statement, which you prove by using again `M.find_1`, but then you use `M.add_2` and `M.find_2`.